# WebSphere MQ Message Listener Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to figure out how WSMQ handles message listeners and threads.  If I have one instance of a message listener, and have many queues, does each listener create a new thread for each queue?  Or will there be one thread for the listener?  Any insight will greatly help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Websphere, you typically add Listener Ports to the Message Listener Service. Each Listener port is associated with a specific connection factory and a queue through the JNDI name specified in the definition of those resources respectively. You can configure the number of threads at the Message Listener Service level and when the application starts, that many threads will listen on the queue. The Message Listener is attached to a Server and has a 1-many relationship with the Listener Ports.

Comment: Can you provide me with any links to articles that use message listeners?  Thanks.

Comment: Chapter 15 in this performance Redbooks is a good place to start. http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246198.pdf. Though the book references Websphere 5.1, the concepts and the configuration are the same in the latest Websphere release.